# How to push an image to Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble pushing an image to the Docker Hub.
When I try to do that, I get this message 'unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized'.

One article suggested that I log in to the Docker Hub beforehand, which I've already done.
Another article suggested that I change the tag to include explicit port, which ended up giving this message 'Repository does not exist'.

Neither of these articles have solved my problem.

I'm operating Docker version 1.8.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how this is an Ubuntu question.  Docker Hub is controlled by a non-Ubuntu resource/company, and is not an Ubuntu thing.  Unauthorized means you don't have access, which you have to take up with the Docker Hub staff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to create a repository for the image using the docker hub Website.

To push the image from the command line you need to login using "docker login" first:

```
  % docker login                                                           
  Username: yourname
  Password: ********
  Email: you@youremail.com
  Login Succeeded

  % docker push image:tag
```

That should do.

Comment: It turned out that I was trying to access a wrong repository that didn't exist in my Docker Hub. Thanks for your comment "create a repository". After I created an "appropriate" repository, I was able to push my image. Thanks!!